# Why MyClass.class.superclass in Ruby is Module

Tags: ruby, class

I had a class named MyClass in ruby.
When I check it in irb as

```
>class MyClass
>end

> MyClass.class.superclass
```

I get

```
 => Module
```

I need to know the technical description of this output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets look at this code:

```
MyClass.class #=> Class
```

Funky. So a class, is actually an instance of the class named `Class`. Meaning these two lines are pretty similar:

```
class MyClass; end
MyClass = Class.new
```

And these are similar, too.

```
class MyClass; end;
myInstance = MyClass.new

myInstance = Class.new.new # I know this looks funky, but it works
```

So now we get to:

```
MyClass.class.superclass #=> Module
```

So the class named `Class` inherits from `Module`. This makes sense since a `Class` behaves just like a `Module` except that you can instantiate it, and it cannot be included.

---

Checkout the docs for [`Class`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Class.html) and for [`Module`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html) for more info and how those two classes work.

Realizing that ruby is "turtles all the way down" is important. And a class object being an instance of class `Class` is one of the best examples of that, if you can get your head around it :)